# Improve UI for headers with proper markdown

Tags: bug, design, markdown

The rendering of headers created through markdown seems a bit off to me. Specifically, the spacing doesn't strongly enough suggest that it is a header *for the section that **follows***.

### What I should do

I'm guessing I'm supposed to do this to insert headers in my post to create sections:

```
What I should do
----------------
I'm guessing I'm supposed to do this to insert headers in my post to create sections:
```

However, the rendering shows "What I should do" with about equal space above and below the header. I want to have the header visually linked to the *following* section more than the one before it.

**What I tend to do**
It's bad (semantics-wise), but I still tend to use this:

```
**What I tend to do**  
It's bad (semantics-wise), but I still tend to use this:
```

Note that there's **two spaces** after the first line to force a linebreak (shudder!). The added bonus in my personal opinion of this approach (specifically for short posts) is that the size of the font isn't so dramatically increased as with the headers.

### What I've also considered

Using a forced linebreak before the header:

```
  
What I've also considered
---------------------
Using a forced linebreak before the header:
```

Again, with two spaces on the first line (they are em-spaces in this post, because regular spaces at the start of a code block aren't rendered either).

This *does not work in preview*, but as it turns out it *does work in the final version* (a bit too well I guess)...

[image: headers with less margin-bottom]

In short, quite a bit less `margin-bottom` on the rendered headers.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Removing the `.post-text h1, .post-text h2, .post-text h3 { margin-bottom: 1em; }` rule would achieve what you want. Note you can do that on your side with the proper tools.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/238749/revisions)'s a sandbox post that demonstrates the issue a bit better (imho), you can use it in your post if you want.

Comment: Similar request on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82281/can-we-balance-the-whitespace-above-below-headings

Comment: @Stijn Good point. A duplicate, even, I guess.