# Better distinction between h1 and h2 tags created with markdown

Tags: bug, design, markdown

In addition to [my older request about margins around headers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270153/419956), I'd also like to suggest that the distinction between large and small headers can be improved. Take for example:

```
# Header
Some main introduction about...

## Subheader 1
The first thing about this is...

## Subheader 2
The second thing about this is...
```

Or, the same thing:

```
Header
====
Some main introduction about...

Subheader 1
----
The first thing about this is...

Subheader 2
----
The second thing about this is...
```

Both render in a way it's rather hard to distinguish between an `h1` and an `h2`. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Rendered headers]

As the Non-Designer's Design Book would probably put it: if you're going to make things different, make them *really* different. I think that bit of advice wouldn't hurt here. What do you guys think?